# Node sequelize not creating associations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, associations, model-associations

I am unable to create associations with sequelize in nodejs, it's creaing only booking not creating Notes automatically.

here is my code

**db.js**

```
async function initialize() {   

   db.Booking = require('../bookings/booking.model')(sequelize);
   db.Note = require('../notes/note.model')(sequelize);

   db.Note.belongsTo( db.Booking );
   db.Booking.hasMany( db.Note );

}
```

**booking.service.js**

```
async function create(params) {
   const data = await db.Booking.create(params, { include: [{model: db.Note, as: 'Notes'}] }).then( async ( booking ) => {});
});
```

i am passing ***params*** like this

```
{
   "status": "Active",
   "oneTime": "0",
   "start": "2021-12-25",
   "end": "2021-12-25",
   "Notes": [
      {
          "text": "This an test",
          "private": 0
      }
   ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone who can help :(

Answer (score 0):

Notes Parameter was missing in validation schema, because if this sequelize was unable to get Notes data :P